# I want a cell on one sheet to equal a cell on another sheet but only if not blank, If blank i don't want it to do anything at all

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel workbook and the numbers in one cell on a sheet (sheet called 'LCM1225'  which is my master data) I want put into another sheet (Sheet called 'Cap Study SC05L').

I can easily do the ..     ='LCM1225'!W5     so that in my Cap Study SC05L sheet cell I85 = whatever numbers are typed into sheet LCM1225 cell W5.

However, my cap study sheet has many calculations for min and max and if any of the cells going down from I85 to I210 are blank it will only calculate what numbers are there,  if I use the '=' then it appears as 0 if the LCM1225 master data is blank, and therefore calculates minimum value as 0 so cap study not correct.

I tried unticking in the options the change cell to 0 if no value but does not work,  I also tried the  `='LCM1225'!W5 & ""` which looks like it works but all data is all text and therefore nothing calculated.   Everything i try i get errors in all the cap study formulas if anything other than absolutely nothing is showing in that cell.

I am needing a simple this cell equals that cell but only if not blank, and if it's blank i don't want it to do anything at all until someone types in numerical result in the LCM1225 master sheet.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: did you try: `=IF('LCM1225'!W5="","",'LCM1225'!W5)`

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(...);"";...)`

Comment: Scott Craner,  that worked perfect,  thank you so much, i've been on days trying to figure this out.